# How can I keep the pdf page from wrapping to a new page when large amounts of information is disaplayed

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I have a specific question. What is going on is that I have created a PDF form using mPDF.  The problem that I'm having is when there is a large amount of data, the form goes over into a different page. Is there a way to prevent the PDF to overflowing to a different page despite the large amounts of data on the page.

Thank you...

Comment: Yes tell mPDF you want a different page size for this document

Answer (score 0):

You may choose to reconfigure the page size of the PDF you are working on (bigger page = more text per page). However: if you plan to print this form on standard 8.5" x 11" printer paper, this is not the solution for you.

You can also shrink the font size you are using to allow more text to fit on the page. Keep in mind that the trade-off to smaller text is that you loose readability.

Depending on the layout of your document, you may also be able to tweak its design making it more space-efficient. This would be the most involved solution to your problem, but could potentially be the best, for you would be able to preserve the font and page size.